# Check if these vectors form a basis

Tags: vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I am having trouble trying to solve this problem:

**Check that the following vectors are bases and find the dimension of the vector space they are basis for**

- $S_1 = (1,0,...,0),(0,1,...,0),...,(0,0,...,1) \in K^n$

  I do not know how can I put these vectors in row echelon form since I don't know how many they are or all their components.
- $S_2 = 1,x,x^2,...,x^n\subset K^n$ [x]=“Polynomials of degree less than or equal to n”

  How do i put these in row echelon form?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $S_1$ is in row echelon form all ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first set of vectors contains $n$ vectors, where the $k$th one has zeros everywhere except in coordinate number $k$. For instance if $n=3$ we have $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

If you just write them in a matrix in the order they come, it is already in row echelon form. You just need to verify that it is a basis, which should be quite easy regardless of your preferred method of doing so.

Your second set of vectors seems ill-defined; what is $x$ and how does it give a $n$-dimensional vector?

Assuming that $x$ is an element of $K$, and the vectors you want are $(1,0,0,...)$, $(0,x,0,...)$, $(0,0,x^2,...)$ et cetera it should be almost exactly the same as the previous one.

And btw, to get it to be in $K^n$, you have to stop at $x^{n-1}$ since you included $1=x^0$.

**edit:**

With the new information, I interpret the second question as us being given a $K$-vector space $W$ spanned by the elements $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$.

It is indeed a $K$-vector space, with addition of two vectors in the usual sense, and multiplication of vectors with scalars (elements of $K$) also defined in the usual way.

To see the dimension, you just have to realise that $1,x,...,x^n$ are all linearly independent elements, and that their span is $n+1$-dimensional.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! Know that is defined, could you help me ?

Comment: And thanks for your help in number 1!

Comment: @Laura, I added some more paragraphs. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! You’ve really helped me @neptun